# Delay submitting $Ajax formData in Production

Tags: ajax, node.js

I'm submitting a form via $ajax to Node.js, and then uploading from there to Dropbox.

Locally, the form submit hits the route to upload the file in my server almost instantly. However, when on Heroku, there is a pretty significant lag. I'm logging the moment the route is hit, and it can take several minutes. Feels like the client is processing all the formData before sending it server-side. Is this normal behavior? Obviously the wait time is shorter on smaller file sizes.

Is there a way to track the progress on this processing? I have a file progress bar that starts, once the route in my server is hit (uploading to DropBox). But before then, it just hangs and it confusing to the user.

### angular-app.js

```
$.ajax({
  type : 'POST',
  url: path_to_server_to_process_form,
  data: formData,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  success: function (data) {
      console.log(data)
  },
  error: function (e, error, errorMessage) {
    console.log(errorMessage);
  }
})
```

### Node server.js

```
    server.post('/route_for_processing_form', function (req, res){ 
 // It takes a while before hitting this route. 
}
```

Comment: To me it simply sounds like you're describing the time it takes for the client to actually upload the file. Locally it would of course upload much faster. and, yes, that progress can be tracked.

Comment: Ah. Seems wasteful in production to have the client upload the file to the server, then shoot it to Dropbox. Although technically the server to dropbox upload process can happen behind the scenes, and I'm better off just showing progress on the client > server upload.